# Best practice to login with a connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have a User table in my database which I use to login as a user. To connect against the database, I need to use a connection string with already filled data like `XXXUser` and `XXXPassword`.

I can't tell if that's the most secure way to connect to my database since I have to save this connection string in my `appsettings.json` with filled user data. So should I create a user for each new user in my database and not in a user table? Is my solution a common way to solve user handling?

```
ConnectionString": "Data Source = XXX.server.net; Initial Catalog = XXXDataBase; User ID = XXXUser; Password = XXXPassword; Connect Timeout = 30;
```

Comment: `appsettings.json` stays server-side, so you can use the same connection string for all users

Comment: Your connection identity usually is independent of user identity

Comment: If that' the case I already have the right Solution I think. thank you

Comment: and what happens if i do something like this with the secret in the AppSetting clas? 

services.Configure<TriTolo.AppSetting>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));